# Blender facial / mouth rig by seperate bones, not shapes?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, parent

Thanks for stopping by.

So I'm trying to rig my characters mouth now, and I'm aiming for more emoji style mouth expressions, so I would like to use bones, and not different shapes. The mouth is a flattened sphere. I've weight painted it appropriately, with the left, right, top and bottom each having a share on disconnected bones.

I'm not sure whats wrong, but whenever I move the four bones that are weighted nothing happens. the mouth does move when I rotate the head, but in a kind of deformed messed up way. I think something isn't parented right?

If anyone has any input I would appreciate it! I'll try to attach a picture to show what I mean...[image][image]

Thank you!

Comment: The bones controlling the mouth would normally be placed on the surface of the mesh and would be parented to the head bone so that they move with the head.

Comment: sidenote just to help you. If you want to control the mouth expressions from a offset control rig you would need shapekeys with drivers. shapekeys are probably the best anyways for emoji expressions

Comment: It would help, if you'd upload the .blend file. It's hard to guess, what is the cause just by description, but in general HenrikD is right. Shapekeys in this case are better option, much less work, more control over the mouth shape.